# Sizeof array through function in C

Tags: c, arrays, search, sizeof, sequential

I'm not sure why I cannot use sizeof(array) when passing the array through my function only outputs a value of 1, instead of 1000000. Before passing the array to the function, I printed out the sizeof(array) to get 4000000 and when I try to printout the sizeof(array) in the function, I only get 4. I can iterate through the array in both the function and the main to display all values, I just cannot display sizeof within the function. Did I pass the array through incorrectly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
searchMe(int numbers[], int target)
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(numbers));
    int position = -1;

    int i;
    int k = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);   

    for (i = 0; i < k && position == -1; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == target)
        {
            position = i;
        }
    }
    return position;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int numbers[1000000];
    int i;
    int search;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        numbers[i] = i;
    }

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &search);

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(numbers));
    int position = searchMe(numbers, search);

    printf("Position of %d is at %d\n", search, position);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int searchMe(int numbers[], int target)
```

is equivalent to

```
int searchMe(int *numbers, int target)
```

There is a special C rules for function parameters that says parameters of array type are *adjusted* to a pointer type.

It means in your program that `sizeof numbers` actually yields the size of the `int *` pointer type and not of the array.

To get the size you have to add a third parameter to your function and explicitly pass the size of the array when you call the function.

Comment: It should be noted that unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, *any* array expression will be converted from type "N-element array of `T`" to "pointer to `T`".  IOW, the type of `numbers` isn't changed in the function, it's changed before the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays are passed as reference. Meaning only pointer to array is passed. **Sizeof** inside the function would only print the size of pointer, not the size of array.

Besides just making sure you know, size of returns number of bytes, so if you have an integer array (where int is of size 4 for e.g. sizeof would give elements * 4 as output.

Comment: This is called "array decay", BTW