# Sizeof pointer of pointer in C

Tags: pointers

I have this function:

```
byte GD_FindButton(BUTTON **array, TPoint *Touchposition)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(**array); i++)
    {
        if ((Touchposition->x > (*array)->x1) && (Touchposition->x < (*array)->x2) && (Touchposition->y > (*array)->y1) && (Touchposition->y < (*array)->y2))
            return (*array)->name;
        array++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

where `**array` is a pointer of pointer declare as is:

```
BUTTON **button_array[2] = { &home, &start };
```

that contain

```
BUTTON home = { 20, 145, 70, 195, 'h' };
BUTTON start = { 84, 33, 236, 185, 's' };
```

I have to detect the size of the `**button_array` for prevent overflow during the for loop but I have problem to understand how to do.
Can you help me? 
Thanks!!

Comment: You cannot use `sizeof` on array passed as function argument. The above thread explains why this is.

Comment: Maybe the answer here explains it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897716/sizeof-array-through-function-in-c