# sizeof(<array of strings>) constantly returns 8

Tags: c, arrays, types, char, size

I'm trying to use the trick to get the number of items in an array by dividing the array size by the size of the type: `sizeof(array) / sizeof(<type>)` or `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`

For reasons I don't fully understand, when I try to take an array as an argument to a function as type `const char**` and then call `sizeof()`, it always returns 8.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void write(const char** arr) {
    printf("%ld", sizeof(arr));
}

int main() {
    const char* word[] = {
        "asdf",
        "qwer",
        "hjkl"
    };

    write(word);

    return 0;
}
```

```
>> 8
```

So `sizeof(array) / sizeof(const char*)` always just comes out to 1.

What's going on?

Comment: That `printf` doesn't generate that output. You should post something that actually compiles without warnings. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry about that, had to go out.

Comment: When you pass an array to a function, the array decays to a pointer. So as far as the `write` function is concerned `arr` is a pointer, and `sizeof(arr)` is the size of a pointer. [Here's a link to a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897716)

Answer (score 1):

Is that really your `printf()`?  If so, it is totally wrong, you have no format string:

```
int main(void) {
    const char* word[] = {
        "asdf",
        "qwer",
        "hjkl"
    };


    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(word));
}
```

output :

```
12
```